# With these queries, it is possible to achieve this with Firestore without needing Cloud Functions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nosql

I'm building an app using Firebase Firestore + ReactJS where there will only be 1 user to add orders and manage the inventory.

**Manage Inventory**

- CRUD Product
- CRUD size & quantity (there could be multiple sizes)
- CRUD color & quantity (there could be multiple colors)

It will also subtract the quantities for the specific product's size and color once an order was placed.

**Ordering**

- Choose Product
- Enter Quantity
- Choose its sizes and color

**For example:**
There was an order for notebooks and cups in one order. Let's assume that there was already a name, address, and phone number entered. The chosen order will be:

**1st item:**

- Notebook
- 3 pieces
- 1st piece: Size: small, color: red
- 2nd piece: Size: medium, color: green
- 3rd piece: Size: Large, color: blue

**2nd item:**

- Cup
- 2 pieces
- 1st piece: Size: small, color: red
- 2nd piece: Size: Large, color: blue

I have this data structure in mind. However, I could not grasp how to structure if there are multiple pieces of the same products and each would have different `sizes` and `colors`. In the `order collection`, for the fields product, `sizes`, and `color`, I was thinking of using an `array` or `map`. I'm not sure about this yet. Any help would be most appreciated.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzdbo.png]

I tried structuring it in Firestore just for an example and I am not sure with the part of the order collection for the field `products`:

[image]

And this is what I came up with the Inventory collection:
[image]

Are these queries possible in Firestore without needing Cloud Functions?
Like those products with their sizes and colors that were placed will also be subtracted in the inventory?

Comment: There is no singular correct way to model data in a NoSQL database based on the structure. Instead it all depends on the use-cases of your app, which we (and probably even you) don't know yet. So instead of giving us the big overview and asking for validation, can you give us one use-case that you're struggling with and showing us the data structure as it is relevant to that, and what exactly it is that you can't get to work? That will make it more more likely that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ohh alright. But with these queries, is it possible to achieve with firestore without needing the cloud functions?

Comment: Hi, Can you be more precise with your question as suggested by Frank, also can you be more clear with this question: ```But with these queries, is it possible to achieve with firestore without needing the cloud functions?```?

Comment: @ZeenathSN I've edited the question. I just want to ask if querying is possible with Firestore such as saving multiple products with its' different sizes and color and then those products that were placed will also be subtracted in the number of stocks in the inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write Firestore queries in your React JS code instead of creating a separate Cloud Functions for it. You can treat it like any other NoSQL database and work with it.

You can also add various data types like an array as you have mentioned in your question as shown in the datatypes section of [add data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types).

You can use set() to add data into the Firestore, and use update() whenever you want to update a field without overwriting the entire document. You can use update() to update the stocks present in the inventory.

You can  learn more about adding data into Firestore and updating the data with the help of [this Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).